# Why is my integration wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int x(x+1)^{-1/3} dx$$

My definition of integration by parts:

$$\int uv^{\prime}dx = uv - \int v u^{\prime}dx$$

Using this:
$$\int x(x+1)^{-1/3}dx  = x \int(x+1)^{-1/3} dx - \int (x+1)^{-1/3}x^\prime dx \text{ (Integration by Parts)}$$
$$\int (x+1)^{-1/3} = \frac{3}{2}(x+1)^{2/3} + c$$
$$\implies \int x(x+1)^{-1/3}dx  = x \frac{3}{2}(x+1)^{2/3} - \frac{3}{2}(x+1)^{2/3} 
$$

But Wolfram Alpha disagrees. What am I missing?

Comment: The very first line is wrong. Please describe the beginning of your integration by parts. This is where you have a mistake.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I added what I think integration by parts is. Is my definition wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The expression you currently have is

$$\int uv^{\prime}dx = uv - \int \color{red}{v^{\prime}} u^{\prime}dx$$

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you wrote, you set
u = x and v' = (1+x)^(-1/3)
Then, u' = 1 and v = (3/2) (1+x)^(2/3)
You then have as a result : (3/2) x (1+x)^(2/3) - (3/2) Integral[(1+x)^(2/3)]
The last integral is (3/5) (1+x)^(5/3)
Then, the total result is (3/2) x (1+x)^(2/3) - (3/2) (3/5) (1+x)^(5/3)
Grouping terms, you finally arrive to (3/10) (1+x)^(2/3) (2x-3).
Derive this last expression and you will arrive to x (1+x)^(1/3)